# How to detect CAD dwg/dxf file is 2D or 3D?

Tags: dll, cad, dxf, dwg

I want to use CAD dwg/dxf file, but before use I need to identify programmatically that the given file is 2D file or 3D file.

So, is there a way to detect CAD dwg/dxf file is 2D or 3D?

Please suggest any way to detect that given file is 2D or 3D.

Please note that I want to detect 2D/3D from server.

Comment: Did you try checking if the drawing contains any 3DSOLID entity?

Comment: Do you consider the file to be 3D if any object has a non-zero Z-component?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about dwg/dxf file. I am just looking for library(jar/dll) to detect that given file(dwg/dxf) is 2D or 3D.

Comment: I think you will find this hard to work out. There is no specific variable in the DXF file that you can look up. There are 3D elements that can still have a elevation of 0. 2D elements can technically also have an elevation. So as per the second comment by @LeeMac I think you would have to walk the elements and see if any have a non-zero Z component.